# Selection of multiple images from gallery view

Tags: android, android-gallery, custom-adapter

I want to create a gallery view, in which I want to select multiple images using an orange rectangular box.

It should look something like the following:

[image: gallery view]

screen look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsNAa.jpg

Comment: Have you tried any code? Please provide code, so SO users will help you.

Comment: I feel like you want me to write an entirely new code for you for the shake of 100 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can define a custom adapter for your GalleryView, define a row XML layout file with ImageView and CheckBox and inflate this XML layout inside the custom adapter class. FYI, you will define custom adapter class by extending `BaseAdapter` class.

Check this example: [Android custom image gallery with checkbox in grid to select multiple](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want to select multiple images using a rectangle box, not using check box, In given picture the orange color box used to select multiple images

Comment: what do you mean by rectangle box?

Comment: Above picture there are a orange color box are used to select multiple image

Comment: How to solve this, I want to select multiple images using a orange frame of box which are showing?

Comment: After 2 month I am still do not get the output like this.

Comment: After 1 year I am still do not get the output like this

Answer (score 5):

### Issues in your design:

Doing the selection by dragging the thumbs on either sides is going to be an extra headache. First of all, handling scrolling while doing selection. Secondly, handling touch/drag and deciding whether to include an item in the selection or not.

### **Design change:**

Let me suggest a simpler way to extend your selection rectangle **:**

I assume the selection starts  with a long click on any item. The orange selection rectangle appears over this *initial* item. Then a single tap on any neighboring item should include all items placed in-between the tapped and the *initial* item including the tapped one. That will make selection handling significantly simpler and less buggy.

### **Implementation:**

Now this design shouldn't be too difficult to implement. Extend the Gallery widget and have members that indicate whether a selection is in progress and what is the range of selection (`startIndex` and `endIndex`) .
Override the `onDraw` method and draw the selection rectangle from `startIndex` to `endIndex` items.

Comment: Finally you had to settle for checkbox based solution.. Thats the best way to select a subset of items.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do:

- Give ids all the images in the slide show
- Use javascript to set
- onclick events for the images Enable borders on the onclick event

Add to img tags

```
<IMG id=”1” namespace=”clicked” onclick="TriggerEvent(this)"></IMG>
```

Create script trigger event that changes the namespace of the selected id.

Include css to enable the borders:

```
.clicked{
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;}
```